# como puedo usar el mismo objeto ya creado en el form1 en el form2

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo esta clase

```
 public class lista
{
   Nodo l;
   public lista()
   {
       l = null;

   }
   public void insertar(int elem)
   {
       if (l == null)
       {
           l = new Nodo(elem);
            aux = l;
        }
       else
       {
            aux = l;
           while (aux.prox != null) aux = aux.prox;
           Nodo p = new Nodo(elem);
           aux.prox = p;

       }

   }
    Nodo aux;
   public string mostrar()
   {

       //Nodo aux = l;
        string p = "";

       if(aux!=null)
        {
            p= aux.elem.ToString();
            aux = aux.prox;
        }
        return p;
        //
    }
}
```

desde el form1 cargo la lista con el procedimiento Insertar
despues en el form2 quiero que los muestre 
pero al inicializar el form2 se instancia otro objto para poder acceder a la lista y como es otro objeto esta vacio 
lo que intento hacer es acceder a lo que ya se cargo en el objeto del form1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen diferentes formas de pasar datos entre formularios.

Una de las más sencillas es hacerlo a través del constructor: crea un constructor en el formulario `Form2` que acepte un argumento de tipo `lista` y le pasas el objeto creado en el `Form1`.

En el `Form2` el constructor te quedaría:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{

    public Form2(lista datos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    .....
```

Y en el `Form1` crearías la instancia de `Form2` pasando el objeto `lista`:

```
lista miLista = new lista();

// Código inicialización objeto milista
// .....

var newForm2 = new Form2(miLista);
newForm2.Show();
```

Comment: sii me parece bien pero si en el form1 añade otro elemento a la lista porq el form2 tiene que recorrer de acuerdo lo que va ingresando el form1 la idea es hacer una fila como los bancos esperando su turno

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres. Igual sería bueno que editaras la pregunta para detallar mejor tu caso. En cualquier caso, tal y como yo te lo planteo, en los dos formularios tendrías una referencia a la misma instancia del objeto así que cualquier modificación realizada desde un formulario se podría ver desde el otro.

Comment: tienes razon .. muchas gracias por tu ayuda funciona lo que me planteas gracias

Comment: +1 por no recomendar variables variables estáticas.